# RenderSection in <head > missing text

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

**Update :** a co-worker told me that this is a known bug in the MVC4 beta.  The issue is caused by the } bracket from the javascript causing RenderSection to think that the section has ended.

I have a rendersection in the  of my layout for page specific jquery.  It is not properly copying the code from my Views into the render section.

I have the following in my _Layout.cshtml (the template _Layout.cshtml + my new section)

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/AjaxLogin.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        @RenderSection("jqueryheader", false)

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
```

I have the following code in my Index.cshtml

```
@section jqueryheader {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var listid = '@(Model.ID)';
        $("#additem").load("~/Item/AddItem/" + listid);
    });
</script>
}
```

I get the following output in IE:

```
<script src="/Scripts/AjaxLogin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var listid = '9f3348ef-f713-48c6-a267-3777182cf39e';
        $("#additem").load("~/Item/AddItem/" + listid);


        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
```

Anyone know why RenderSection missed the `});</script>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you want to put your JavaScript in the header?

I'm not 100% sure what the issue is here, but here is a best practices suggestion.  I am going to advise that you put this script at the bottom of your view/page.  It's best practices.  So in your layout view/master page, just before you close off your body tag do the following:

```
<body>

     <!-- Other HTML code -->

     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/JavaScripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")"></script>
     @RenderSection("JavaScriptBodySection", false)

</body>
```

And then in your view you just do this:

```
@section JavaScriptBodySection
{
     <script>

          $(document).ready(function () {
               var listid = '@(Model.ID)';
               $("#additem").load("~/Item/AddItem/" + listid);
          });

     </script>
}
```

I also have my meta tags like you because my doc type was HTML 4.01 strict.  I never had this issue.  I just put ALL of my JavaScript at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it works.  Thanks for the best practices tip, I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

The possible reason maybe will be that your `<meta>` tag doesn't closed properly which brings such result in IE.

Try to close your `<meta>` tag by `/>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: You're Chuck Norris, really! I'm sure you are... :D